# Are Matlab applications compiled on Windows runnable under Linux?

Tags: matlab, cross-platform, matlab-compiler

Application complied in windows `MATLAB R2014b`, is it runnable in Linux (`Ubuntu 14.04`) with the Linux [MCR](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. Applications produced by MATLAB Compiler are platform-specific, so if you want to run it on Linux you'll need to compile it on Linux.

However, licenses of MATLAB and MATLAB Compiler are not platform-specific, so you should be able to install the same copy of MATLAB and MATLAB Compiler on Linux in order to produce a Linux application.